# $B$ be an Infinite dimensional Banach Space and $T:B\to B$ be an continuos operator

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Let $B$ be an Infinite dimensional Banach Space and $T:B\to B$ be an continuous operator such that $T(B)=B$ and $T(x)=0\Rightarrow x=0$

which of the following is correct?

1. $T$ maps bounded sets into compact set
2. $T^{-1}$ maps bounded sets into compact set
3. $T^{-1}$ maps bounded sets into bounded set
4. $T$ maps compact sets into open set
   I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: Isn't this the bounded inverse theorem (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem), and hence the 3rd option?

Comment: Everything is always mapped *into* open sets.  Should 4. say "*onto* open sets"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$1.$ and $2.$ are not satisfied by $Tx=x$.

$3.$ $T^{-1}$ is bounded (as a consequence of the closed graph theorem).

$4.$ Take $K:=\{0\}$.

Comment: Davide could you tell me how $T^{-1}$ is bounded?

Comment: What did your attempt with closed graph theorem give?